# data handling in R

Tags: r, list

I have data in R like:

```
[[90]]
   b                c       a      d     
  NULL              NULL   NULL  NULL
"pears soap set"    "NA"   "NA"   "NA"  

 [[91]]
   b                            c      a      d     
    NULL                       NULL  NULL  NULL 
  "dermi cool powder lavender" "NA"  "NA"   "NA"  

 [[92]]
   b          c      a      d     
  NULL       NULL   NULL   NULL
 "polyclav" "375"  "NA"   "tab"
```

Now I want the data to become:

```
"pears soap set"            "NA"  "NA" "NA"
"dermi cool powder lavender""NA"  "NA" "NA"
"polyclav"                   "375""NA" "tab"
```

How could this be done.

Thanks

Comment: Can you `dput()` your data? It would be very helpful.

Comment: How did you create your data? Why does it contain all these `NULL` values? Why do you have `"NA"` strings instead of `NA` values? I think you should fix other parts of your code.

Comment: You likely want `do.call(rbind,data)`